Calibre viewer doesn't fill window
I've tried every configuration I can imagine to solve this, I just can't figure out why Calibre refuses to fill the viewer window. I'm using i3 in Debian, if that is of any relevance. This is what the viewer looks like:


I'm talking about the massive empty space beneath the page view, regardless of the file type, any settings I've changed, the text view only occupies that small piece of the window.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, I can't seem to find any reference to this problem anywhere. Thanks!
Edit: Other things I’ve tried
I installed gnome just to see if i3 was the issue, it was not, it did the same thing in gnome.

I have the same issue with Calibre 7.19 (after an upgrade to Linux Mint 22 Wilma), October 2024.

Though Calibre is a superb tool, some of its E-book Viewers are poorly implemented -- they are slow to start, and often have flaws.
However, Calibre allows you to set other viewers quite simply, so if the default book viewer for a particular file type is bad, choose another.


In Preferences, select Behavior.
In the right pane, for each file type, select either Calibre internal E-book Viewer, or, if the box is not selected, the preferred viewer of the operating system will be used.

For example, I set Sumatra PDF, in both Windows, and in Ubuntu, running under wine, as the default application to open both EPUB and PDF files, because it is fast and less demanding of resources.  Some alternatives are Okular, FBReader, and others.
A right-click on a Calibre entry still permits opening with the internal viewer.

I rolled back to version 7.10 of Calbire and that resolved the issue, must be a bug in one of the more recent versions.

I have the same issue with Calibre 7.19 (which I got while updating Linux Mint to version 22 Wilma.)
Is there a way for me to downgrade Calibre without recompiling the older version of it? (I remember that compiling Calibre is tricky...)
Many thanks!

I didn’t compile it at all, I just installed an older version from their website. Had to go back several versions but that did it.
